# Include variable in Django template loop

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a for loop in a Django template, which prints out a list of books, which works well. The issue comes when I try to mark one of the items in the list as selected, based on a value passed in from the views.py file:

```
<select name="b">
    <option value="1">Book</option>
    {% for book in books %}
        <option {% if book.id == selected_book %} selected {% endif %} value="{{ book.id }}">{{ book.t }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

The "books" variable is a list, passed in from the views.py file. I can access these variables fine outside of the loop, but if I try to include a seperate variable inside the loop ("selected_book"), I have issues.

The above code does nothing, and if I try to wrap the variable in double brackets

`{{ selected_book }}`

I get the following error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError 
Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'
```

The variable is being passed into the template, because I can get it to print to the page. I only get an error when I try to use it in the for loop.

If I write "{% if book.id == 2 %}" that works fine.

Comment: you need to change `"{{ book.id }}"` to `{{ book.id }}`

Comment: make sure ``book.id`` is really there. is "books" a list of objects?

Comment: Book ID isn't the problem. If I write "{% if book.id == 2 %}" that works fine.

Comment: The template code looks fine. What is the value of `selected_book`? Are you absolutely sure it's an integer? Could you post your `views.py` too?

Comment: Good man! You're right, it was a string. I was getting it as a GET parameter in my views.py file: "request.GET['b']". Converting it to an int worked: int(request.GET['b']). Please construct your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that `selected_book` is an integer not a string, otherwise the code is fine